# Get Gap between time range

Tags: oracle, datetime, plsql, oracle11g

In `WORK_TIME` column in my database table (`EMP_WORKS`), i have records as below.

```
WORK_TIME

19:03:00
20:00:00
21:02:00
21:54:00
23:04:00
00:02:00
```

i want to create a database `view` using these data. for it i need to get `Gap` between these times as below.

```
WORK_TIME  GAP

19:03:00  -
20:00:00  00:57:00  (Gap between 19:03:00 and 20:00:00)
21:02:00  01:02:00  (Gap between 20:00:00 and 21:02:00)
21:54:00  00:52:00  (Gap between 21:02:00 and 21:54:00)
23:04:00  01:10:00  (Gap between 21:54:00 and 23:04:00)
00:02:00  00:58:00  (Gap between 23:04:00 and 00:02:00)
```

How could i do this ?

Comment: :Use `LAG` analytical function to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your desired result, provided in the question,  you want to see time interval. And also I suppose that the `WORK_TIME` column is of `date` datatype and there is a date part(otherwise there will be a negative result of subtraction (previous value of `WORK_TIME` from `00.02.00`)).

```
SQL> create table Work_times(
  2    work_time
  3  ) as
  4  (
  5  select to_date('01.01.2012 19:03:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
  6  select to_date('01.01.2012 20:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
  7  select to_date('01.01.2012 21:02:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
  8  select to_date('01.01.2012 21:54:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
  9  select to_date('01.01.2012 23:04:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
 10  select to_date('02.01.2012 00:02:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual
 11  )
 12  /

Table created

SQL> 
SQL> select to_char(t.work_time, 'hh24.mi.ss') work_time
  2         , (t.work_time -
  3            lag(t.work_time) over(order by WORK_TIME)) day(1) to second(0) Res
  4  from work_times t
  5  ;

WORK_TIME RES
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
19.03.00  
20.00.00  +0 00:57:00
21.02.00  +0 01:02:00
21.54.00  +0 00:52:00
23.04.00  +0 01:10:00
00.02.00  +0 00:58:00

6 rows selected
```

Answer (score 3):

First you will need to have a primary key in the table containing the DATE/TIME field.

I have set up this [demo on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3ce7c/11) .. Have a look

I have represented the gap as a factor of hours between the two times. You can manipulate the figure to represent minutes, or days, whatever.

```
SELECT 
TO_CHAR(A.WORK_TIME,'HH24:MI:SS') WORK_FROM,
TO_CHAR(B.WORK_TIME,'HH24:MI:SS') WORK_TO,
ROUND(24*(B.WORK_TIME-A.WORK_TIME),2) GAP FROM 
  sample A,
  SAMPLE B
WHERE A.ID+1 = B.ID(+)
```

If your primary key values have difference greater than 1 (gaps within the values of the primary key) then you will need to offset the value dynamically like this:

```
  SELECT 
TO_CHAR(A.WORK_TIME,'HH24:MI:SS') WORK_FROM,
TO_CHAR(B.WORK_TIME,'HH24:MI:SS') WORK_TO,
ROUND(24*(B.WORK_TIME-A.WORK_TIME),2) GAP FROM 
  sample A,
  SAMPLE B
WHERE  b.ID = (select min(C.ID) from sample c where c.id>A.ID)
```

[image: SQL Fiddle Screenshot]

Comment: This won't work if you have gaps in your `ID`s, ant I'd suggest not using the old join syntax `(+)` any more.

Comment: @PeterLang I have edited my answer to account for gaps in the primary key value

Comment: Not sure if you tested your updated query, but SQL-Fiddle says `ORA-01799: a column may not be outer-joined to a subquery`

Comment: Yes @PeterLang I forgot to remove the (+) join indicator

Comment: @AhmadAl-Mutawa Thanks for your solutions. but gaps are incorrect. for a example `Gap between 19:03:00 and 20:00:00` query output is `0.95`. but correct answer is `57 mins`. am i wrong ?

Comment: @Bishan you are not wrong. 0.95 hours is equivelant to 57 minutes (because you will need to multiply 0.95 by 60 to get minutes)

Comment: @AhmadAl-Mutawa - your screen caps look good, but it might be easier to embed your SQL Fiddle example in your answer by using the "Markdown format" option (found when you click down on the arrow to the side of "Run SQL").  Let me know what you think of that format - it's new, and I'd like to make it as useful as I can for you guys!

Comment: Thanks, i will do that in the future

Comment: @Jake..then we'd just copy the markdown content and paste to our SO answer? Was that the thought process?

Answer (score 3):

This query will get you the differences in hours:

```
SELECT
  work_time,
  ( work_time - LAG(work_time) OVER (ORDER BY work_time) ) * 24 AS gap
FROM emp_works
```

Example on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5796a/2) returns this:

```
WORK_TIME                           GAP
November, 07 2012 19:03:00+0000     (null)
November, 07 2012 20:00:00+0000     0.95
November, 07 2012 21:02:00+0000     1.033333333333
November, 07 2012 21:54:00+0000     0.866666666667
November, 07 2012 23:04:00+0000     1.166666666667
November, 08 2012 00:02:00+0000     0.966666666667
```